# Ionic LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm building an app at the moment, where you have a To Do List.
These Task should be saved. I don't know why it doenst work :(
Every time you click on Create Task the task should automatically be saved. 
And every time you open the app it should be displayed.
Here is the Popup with the Create task button

**Popup**

```
$scope.newTask = function() {
  $ionicPopup.prompt({
    title: "New Task",
    template: "Enter Task:",
    inputPlaceholder: "What do you need to do?",
    okText: 'Create Task'
  }).then(function(res) {    // promise 
    if (res) $scope.tasks.push({title: res, completed: false});
  })
};
```

Comment: you're missing an `input` field

Answer (score 1):

You need to use LocalStorage. See if it's helpful: http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/

Comment: the links redirect to the homepage :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to save it using localStorage like this:

```
$scope.newTask = function() {
  $ionicPopup.prompt({
    title: "New Task",
    template: "Enter Task:",
    inputPlaceholder: "What do you need to do?",
    okText: 'Create Task'
  }).then(function(res) {    // promise 
    if (res) 
       var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
       var task = {title: res, completed: false};
       window.localStorage.setItem("Task" + randomNumber, JSON.stringify(testObject));

  })
};
```

Then in your controller you need to retrieve them

```
$scope.readTasks = function() {
   for (var a in localStorage) {
      $scope.tasks.push(JSON.parse(localStorage[a]));
   }
};
```

In your view you can call the function like this:

```
 <ion-content ng-init="readTasks()">
```

Comment: its just dont working, can i maybe send you the whole project and you tell me where the localStorage should be added? i tried it so many times and nothing happened :(